# Why do people say SqlDataReader.GetXXX(i) is faster than SqlDataReader[i]?

Tags: c#, sql, performance, ado.net

---

Update:  Turns out reflection doesn't have to be slow either.  Use Fasterflect (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38840/Fasterflect-a-fast-and-simple-API-for-Reflection-i).  It makes reflections literally (and I mean the word 'literally' in the most literal sense, not figuratively as it's often misused) 100's times faster.

I have gotten my code now to the point that it loads data AND puts the data into my business objects just as fast as sql server management studio can do a select * on the tables.

---

I just ran this piece of code that checks for any of the data types in my table and uses appropriate Get methods:

```
        foreach (var p in obj.Properties)
        {
            object value;
            var i = fieldNumbers[p.Alias];

            if (p.Type == "System.Nullable`1[System.Int16]") value = dr.GetSqlInt16(i);
            else if (p.Type == "System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]") value = dr.GetSqlInt32(i);
            else if (p.Type == "System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]") value = dr.GetSqlDecimal(i);
            else if (p.Type == "System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]") value = dr.GetSqlBoolean(i);
            else if (p.Type == "System.String") value = dr.GetSqlString(i);
            else if (p.Type == "System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]") value = dr.GetSqlDateTime(i);
        }
```

and this:

```
            foreach (var p in obj.Properties)
            {
                object value;
                var i = fieldNumbers[p.Alias];
                value = dr[i];
            }
```

and the second one consistently performs faster.  I was surprised by this but it seems to be true.  Can anyone tell me if I'm overlooking something here because I've seen several people claim using the GetXXX methods perform better.  I timed this as a whole and also timed individual retrieve operations.  Did I really just debunk a myth?

EDIT: After testing some more I found a couple things out.

1st - It 'is' marginally faster (about 8% for the tests I ran) to use a get method that returns a value into a strongly typed variable and I tested this without all the superfluous code above so there was no dispatching or anything like that... just apples to apples.

However, note that I am using the GetSqlXXX functions rather than the GetXXX functions.  This is because the latter cannot be used for null values.  However, the former returns types like SqlInt32 rather than int?.  My fields are not SqlXXX though, they are simple nullable types like int?.  I think this is often going to be the case for most people which means that you don't really get the speed increase of the typed methods unless you want to start working with SqlTypes throughout your code.

Secondly, I noticed that retrieving null values seems to be slower than you would expect in general... but that's just my opinion of course.

EDIT 2: Just for Doug McClean and TheEvilPenguin I timed 'just' the branching as follows:

```
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        long time = 0;

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            var obj = new O();
            obj.Initializing = true;


            sw.Restart();            
            foreach (var p in obj.Properties)
            {
                if (p.Type == "System.Nullable`1[System.Int16]") continue;
                else if (p.Type == "System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]") continue;
                else if (p.Type == "System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]") continue;
                else if (p.Type == "System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]") continue;
                else if (p.Type == "System.String") continue;
            }
            time += sw.ElapsedTicks;
        }
        sw.Stop();
        MessageBox.Show(time.ToString());
```

I had to leave a couple of lines not specific to the branching in there, but you can see that I am only adding up time around the branching.  At first I did it in milliseconds and the result (for about 60k records) was 1.  Obviously each cycle is less than a millisecond so I switched to ticks and the result was 466472 which is less than 1 half of 1 millisecond (unless I got my decimal places mixed up... someone please correct me if I'm off there).  So how expensive is branching? Not.

Actually those results do seem awfully small so someone please correct me if I made a mistake in my test, but either way branching is one of the cheapest things you can do.

Comment: With GetXXX(), you don't have to cast "object" value.

Comment: @AVD So you are suggesting that if I knew what the type was ahead of time and was putting it into a strongly typed object (of the appropriate type) then it would be faster?  That could be true, but very often we don't know what the type is going to be until run-time so for this scenario that doesn't really help I guess.

Comment: And just for the record, all the things I read were specifically saying it was faster... not just beneficial because you don't have to cast, and that's what I'm addressing here.

Comment: You are the **Developer**, so, how can you say "we don't know what the type is going to be until run-time"?

Comment: In a perfect world everything would be strongly-typed, enjoy every little bit you can

Comment: You have set up a false test. Your code is not equivalent aside from the method of getting the values; You are potentially testing a number of types for each field in the first option. If you don't know what it is up front, there's no benefit to GetXXX().

Comment: @AndrewBarber True... I have set up a test that is specific to my situation so the results mean a lot more for this specific case than in general, but extra stuff is not 'very' significant.  I tested some other variations and I'm about to edit my post with my findings...

Comment: @AVD Huh? In the example above I can only give 'value' one type but it is handling any number of types.  I suppose that I could make it a generic function but there are numerous cases where even that is not possible and you are passing data through functions that could be any number of types.  I think you know this though so maybe I am misunderstanding your comment.  Feel free to extrapolate if I am.

Comment: @Brandon You're missing my point. There is *no reason* to use GetXXX() if you don't know the type ahead of time and need it typed. I don't even think the "people" who say what you claim are strictly correct, in the first place. The real thing GetXXX(int) is faster than is Get(string)

Comment: @AndrewBarber I see but both examples with and without GetXXX have to cast in my code above and GetXXX has nothing to do with that casting.  I am testing the speed of GetXXX... not the casting that does or does not occur after it returns a value.  So as long as both tests do or both tests don't cast then that shouldn't be an issue.  But I think you are exactly right in regard to your last 2 sentences.

Comment: You aren't just casting... you are often boxing, too. and you are doing string comparisons.

Comment: @AndrewBarber See my last edit in regard to the string comparisons and branching.

Comment: @JohnSaunders A collection of wrappers around the PropertyInfo's for each property in my business object (that relates to a db field).  "p.Type" is a string where the name of the type is cached up front.

Comment: @BrandonMoore really, reflection is not the way to go in an data mapping bit, see dapper or peta poco or any other micro orm for a sane approach.

Comment: @SamSaffron If my only goal was speed then sure.  But speed is actually a second priority to making a tool that speeds development.  The expectation is not that this will be used in the most performance demanding applications, but I want to make performance as good as I can within the confines of the tools purpose.  In any case, there are some things you can do to make reflection quite a bit faster than it is out of the box... but it's still definitely slow compared to not using it.

Comment: see also: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com.au/2012/01/playing-with-your-member.html for faster reflection options, note dapper is all about the api, it happens to be ultra fast, but the clean and rich api is one of its biggest selling point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This all depends on the ADO provider, this answer deals with the SQL Server ADO.NET provider, aka `SqlClient`.

Looking at your benchmark it does not look valid. In particular you are adding a bunch of string comparisons into the mix.

For a valid micro benchmark `GetXYZ` is a *little* bit faster, cause `GetValue` has slightly more overhead, in particular:

1. `GetValue` funnels stuff into the internal `SqlBuffer.Value` that is a simple case statement that dispatches to the same properties `GetXYZ` dispatches.
2. `GetValue` calls `SqlStatistics.StartTimer` whereas the `GetXYZ` calls do not.

It is possible you could IL bake a slightly faster `GetValue()` implementation, I doubt it would be worth it.

The following micro benchmark demonstrates the performance difference:

```
// include Dapper from nuget
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Dapper;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication16
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Integrated Security=True");
            cnn.Open();

            cnn.Execute("create table #t(num int, str nvarchar(50))");

            // 10 k records
            cnn.Execute("insert #t values (@num, @str)", 
                Enumerable.Range(1, 10000).Select(i => new { num = i, str = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() }));

            Stopwatch sw;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from #t");
            cmd.Connection = cnn;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    int num;
                    string str;
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        num = reader.GetInt32(0);
                        str = reader.GetString(1);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("GetXYZ {0}", sw.ElapsedTicks);

                sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    int num;
                    string str;
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        num = (int)reader.GetValue(0);
                        str = (string)reader.GetValue(1);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("GetValue {0}", sw.ElapsedTicks);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
GetXYZ 25094
GetValue 27877
GetXYZ 24226
GetValue 25450
...
GetXYZ 24029
GetValue 26571
```

`GetValue` is consistently ever so slightly slower. 5% worse in the absolute worst case.

Comment: +1 for the insight.  But the string comparisons and branching are insignificant as I showed in my last edit.

Comment: Yep... I did a similar test and pointed out in my edit that I was seeing up to an 8% difference.  But unless I'm missing something, in order to actually benefit from this you would have to start using types like SqlInt32 instead of int?.  I don't think most people would want to do that, at least I wouldn't.

Comment: Anyway, this clearly shows that GetXXX is faster, but I don't think I'll be switching my data types for a 5% increase :)

Comment: @BrandonMoore SqlInt32 is an internal implementation detail, the `GetInt32` returns and int aka. Int32. I would not recommend making any crazy changes to get this tiny perf gain. Only place I would even entertain the thought would be for dapper.

Comment: GetInt32 doesn't play well with int? though :/

Comment: @BrandonMoore IsDBNull is pretty cheap.

Comment: Dapper = Data Mapper? I haven't heard that term before.

Comment: And +1 for the IsDBNull comment... didn't really even think about that.

Answer (score 3):

I would suspect, though I haven't benchmarked, that if you statically know the types of what is associated with each `i`, that it would be possible for the `GetXXX(i)` methods to have a performance advantage over the fully dynamic indexer syntax.

On the other hand, rolling your own dynamic version by dispatching on the type I would not expect to outperform the built in dynamic version, so I'm not really surprised by the example given.

Comment: By 'rolling your own dynamic version by dispatching' are you suggesting that the if statements slow it down significantly?  I highly doubt that but I will test both these theories and let you know the result momentarily.

Comment: Of course they slow things down - branching isn't cheap, and string comparison doesn't exactly take just a handful of cycles either.  These two pieces of code aren't a fair comparison.

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin and whoever just gave him an upvote: See my edit.  Branching is incredibly cheap and string comparisons like this cost very little also.

Comment: Still not a great benchmark - it's quite likely that there's some compiler optimization going on there.  A fairer comparison would be to pick just one of the GetSqlXXX() functions and call it every loop.  There are other things you should do, such as running all code before starting the timer, otherwise you'll just be timing the JIT compiler.

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin I did that and explained my findings in the first edit.  As for the placement of the timer, the timer isn't part of the measurement... it's not 'inside', it's on the outside.  And even if it were on the inside you're talking about a difference that's so insignificant compared to the overall results it's silly to even bring it up.  Instead of ignorantly (no offense) throwing out ideas about why you think this test is skewed why don't you test your ideas first and see for yourself so I don't have to do it for you and tell you why you're wrong ;)

Comment: You asked an argumentative question and then complain when it generates discussion?  I don't have your environment, and don't feel like taking the time to set one up when it's easy to see problems with your benchmarking.  I don't have an opinion about which is faster.  I would just use whichever method is appropriate.  If I want an Object I'd use the indexer, if I want a strongly typed value I'd use the strongly typed overloads.  Please reread my comment about timer placement and JIT - I don't think you understood my point.  Code should be run before benchmark to eliminate compilation delays.

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin I added a benchmark in my answer, so there is a clear answer to this question.

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin You were saying that string comparisons and branching were expensive operations as if they were skewing my results.  Are you suggesting that you're not smart enough to test that theory on your own in like 2 minutes?  I think you probably are smart enough but it's easier to be lazy and talk off the top of your head instead of validating your thoughts first.  And you didn't say the operations 'could' be expensive.  You talked with authority saying 'branching isn't cheap' as if you knew.  Had you simply *suggested* it could be an issue then I wouldn't have complained.

Comment: It's not my job to do the work for you, and I certainly wasn't going to lift a finger once you started insulting me.  I didn't say either operation was computationally expensive, I just said they weren't cheap.  It doesn't seem like any of the methods you're looking at will be expensive, so it doesn't take a lot of cycles to skew the results.  If you can't even be bothered to time your benchmarks properly, I'm not going to go to the trouble of creating a database and coding up a benchmark.  All your benchmarks are flawed, and the one you say refutes me is completely worthless.

Comment: To reiterate, all code you're benchmarking should be run before you start the timer - this means all the code you're benchmarking should be wrapped in a method and executed, and then you can start the timer and execute it again.  There should also be some code inside the if/else blocks to make sure that the compiler doesn't optimize them away.